# why is this not working (js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging

can someone tell why this does not work?
the code does print "generating fish" but than not printing enything...

```
function fish(x, y, degree, genes, Snumber) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.dgree = degree;
            this.energy = 50;
            this.genes = genes;
            this.Snumber = Snumber;
        }

        fishs = new Array(10);
        Snumber = 0;
        document.writeln("generating fish");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            x = Math.round(Math.random * 600);
            y = Math.round(Math.random * 600);
            degree = Math.round(Math.random * 360);
            genes + new Array(12);
            for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                genes[j] = Math.random * 2 - 1;
            }
            fishs[i] = new fish(x, y, degree, genes, Snumber);
            Snumber++;
            document.writeln("genarating fish num" + i);
        }
```

Comment: do not use document.write

Comment: change it to Math.random()

Comment: i am only using it for debugging

Comment: `ReferenceError: genes is not defined`. Just use a debugger.

Comment: [Check your console for errors.](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log#t=20161025164719846478) It will give you plenty of information about what's going on. You can even do `console.log(whateverYouWant)` to check the values of things.

Comment: but then using it like that return NAN

Comment: i changed it, it still does not work

Comment: @yoavsarfaty Have you checked your console? You've got a number of issues. `ReferenceError: genes is not defined`, all of your values are `NaN` because you aren't calling `Math.random`. Replace all of your `document.writeln`s with `console.log` and work with the console. It will make things easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have couple of errors and warnings in your code:

1.) You don't user the `var` keyword, so you automatically put the variables on the global scope.

2.) You use a `+` operator instead of an `=` in the line:

```
genes + new Array(12);
```

3.) You use `Math.random` (wich returns the random function, not a random number) instead of the function in 3 places.

4.) You use `document.write(ln)`, which is deprecated. Use `console.log` instead (which prints to the console, hit F12 to see it)